Unable to connect to ElastiCache Redis Serverless from Spring Boot Application
I have set up an ElastiCache Redis Serverless instance on AWS, and its status is "available". However, I am unable to establish a connection to it from my Spring Boot application. When attempting to connect, I encounter the following error message:
Unable to connect to seerbitbackend-9fekty.serverless.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com/<unresolved>:6379


Checked the security group associated with the ElastiCache instance to ensure that port 6379 is allowed for inbound traffic (0.0.0.0/0).
Verified VPC settings to ensure that there are no restrictions preventing connectivity to the Redis instance.
Attempted to connect using the Redis CLI but received an "operation timed out" error.

Security Group Configuration:
Inbound Rule:
Type: Custom TCP Rule
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 6379
Source: 0.0.0.0/0 (allowing all inbound traffic on port 6379)
The ElastiCache instance is deployed in eu-west-2 (EU-WEST-2) region.
The Spring Boot application uses standard Redis client libraries to connect (spring-boot-starter-data-redis).
What could be causing this issue, and what further steps should I take to diagnose and resolve the connection problem to my ElastiCache Redis Serverless instance?
Thank you

I would also try setting SSL to false in the connection setting. Also, please don't forget to add tcp rule for port 6380. It's written in the official doc. Please refer to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/set-up.html#elasticache-install-grant-access-VPN

Recently, I experienced a similar issue. I solved the issue by checking these two things:
1. Is AmazonElastiCacheFullAccess Policy Permitted for EC2 IAM Role?
According to the ElastiCache documentation, the AmazonElastiCacheFullAccess policy is required to use ElastiCache Serverless. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/set-up.html#elasticache-set-up-permissions)
2. Enable TLS for Spring Boot Data Redis
In order to use ElastiCache Serverless, TLS must be enabled. Therefore, set the spring.data.redis.ssl.enabled option to true in your Spring Boot configuration.(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/appendix/application-properties/index.html#application-properties.data.spring.data.redis.ssl.enabled)

It is important to have build support for TLS when installing
redis-cli. ElastiCache Serverless is only accessible when TLS is
enabled.

